# Giving an example of a "problem" where the example is plural

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I've got this sentence here:

> The most recent problem I can think of is personal knowledge management systems.

That seems grammatically incorrect because of the mismatch between the singular *problem* and the plural *systems*, but I can't just change it to

> The most recent problem I can think of **are** personal knowledge management systems.

or

> The most recent **problems** I can think of **are** personal knowledge management systems.

The only one that seems correct is

> The most recent problem I can think of **is the problem of** personal knowledge management systems.

I think this equates the singular *problem* to the also singular *problem of personal knowledge management systems*. But it's extremely awkward. Any suggestions on how to handle situations similar to this?

Answer (score 3):

It's not grammatically incorrect, but I agree with your instinct that it doesn't sound quite right. I would simply alter this to

"The most recent problem I can think of is *that of* personal knowledge management systems."

Answer (score 2):

> "The most recent **problem** I can think of **is** personal knowledge
>   management systems."

This is correct because the singular (is) agrees with the singular (problem).  Replacing "is" with "are" would be wrong.

> "The most recent problem I can think of is the problem of personal
>   knowledge management systems."

That sentence is too wordy.  You could better rewrite it as:

"Personal Knowledge Management is the most recent problem that comes to mind."

or

"Personal Knowledge Management systems are the most recent problems that come to mind."